# C# how to consume rest web service

Tags: c#, rest, http, webclient, fiddler

I am having a problem when I try using a rest web service in C#.

When I try via Fiddler it works Ok.
When I try via HTML/Ajax, it works Ok, as well.

When I try via C# (Console Application) I get an error.

This image is captured in fiddler. It is what I get when I try via ajax
[image]

this image is also captured in fiddler. It is what I get when I try via C#
[image]

As you can see, the JSON field is empty.

This is my C# code

```
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(abc);

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("MyURL");  //==> I am filling it correctly
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
           new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("MyMethod", json).Result; //==> I am filling my method correctly
```

But I have tried several others and always getting the same problem. (the code bellow is another one I tried)

```
var requisicaoWeb = WebRequest.CreateHttp("MyURL");
        requisicaoWeb.Method = "POST";
        requisicaoWeb.ContentType = "application/json";
        requisicaoWeb.ContentLength = dados.Length;
        requisicaoWeb.UserAgent = "Console app";
        requisicaoWeb.Accept = "Accept:application/json,text/javascript,*/*;q=0.01";


        //precisamos escrever os dados post para o stream
        using (var stream = requisicaoWeb.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(MyJson, 0, dados.Length);
            stream.Close();
        }
        //ler e exibir a resposta
        using (var resposta = requisicaoWeb.GetResponse())
        {
            var streamDados = resposta.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamDados);
            object objResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
            var post = objResponse.ToString();//JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Post>(objResponse.ToString());
            streamDados.Close();
            resposta.Close();
        }
```

Everything I try in C#, the JSON field on Fiddler is always empty and the "syntax View" description is always "Request Invalid".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it's;

```
public static string HttpPost(string URI, string Parameters)
{
    System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URI);

    req.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.Timeout = 600000;
    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Parameters);
    req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    System.IO.Stream os = req.GetRequestStream();
    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    os.Close();
    System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
    if (resp == null)
        return null;
    System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
    return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just figure it out.

If anybody else has the same problem, here is the answer

```
 string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(abc);

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("MyURL");  //==> I am filling it correctly
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
           new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(abc), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"); 

        var response = client.PostAsync("MyURL", stringContent).Result; //==> I am filling my method correctly
```

Comment: *Don't* use `.Result`. In any case, `HttpClient` is a lot easier to use than a raw HttpWebRequest. BTW you don't need to specify UTF8 as an encoding either, it's the default

Comment: @FilipiBraga Check [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this is a console app, so at some point it will have to `Wait` or `Result`

Comment: @Crowcoder not in C# 7.2 and later. Even in earlier versions the blocking call should be the last one in the `Main()` method to avoid deadlocks or other obscure bugs.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Console apps cannot deadlock unless you explicitly set your own synchronization context. The `AsyncMain` in C# 7 is just a convenience method that calls `GetAwaiter.GetResult` (thus blocking) so that you can't do it wrong. I do agree it should be the last call.

Comment: @Crowcoder I'm not refering to sync context deadlocks. Once you start littering async code with `.Result` or `.Wait()` you can end up with one blocked task waiting for another blocked task. It's similar to forgetting to use a `using` block. Yes, if you are very careful you can avoid bugs.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'd like to see a sample console app that deadlocks. I think you are wrong, but I have studied async await to great extent and if you are right I would like to increase my knowledge.

Comment: @Crowcoder by coincidence and courtesy of David Fowler himself https://twitter.com/search?q=david%20fowler&src=typd You don't need a sync context to deadlock. You only need one task blocking on another blocked task

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos am I supposed to be looking at a specific tweet?

Comment: @Crowcoder third or fourth from the top. Correct link here https://twitter.com/davidfowl/status/1044095054875262976

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos OK, setting your own sync context AND contriving a specific scenario with TaskCompletionSource. Good to know but hardly common.